# wso2 debugging a handler in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, wso2, handler

I am new to WSO2. I need to write a new handler. 
Is it possible to debug the handler inside the eclipse?
I saw the documents of WSO2 Developer Studio [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Debugging+Applications) at a glance, but 
it seems the documents are not suitable for beginners and I'm not sure that's about what I mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remotely debug the code from Eclipse. Please follow https://medium.com/@anuradha.15/remote-debugging-wso2-products-using-intellij-idea-ide-c0e828abd700

You need to do the following.

1. Write the handler
2. Engage the handler
3. Start the WSO2 server as mentioned in the above blog.
4. When your code gets hit, you can debug in the Eclipse.